# JQuery. Remove element by attribute name. How?

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to remove a DIV based on it's custom attribute comment_id?

I have the following code but it does not quite work yet.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.delete_comment').live('click', function() {
        // Url we request data from
        $.get( "http://www.site.com/pages/delete/user_comment.php",
        // Url parameters to send 
        {id:$(this).attr('comment_id'),c:'yes'},
        // Output data from php file generated by PHP echo.
        function(data)
        { 
            var comment_id = $(this).attr('comment_id').val();
            //alert(comment_id);
            if (comment_id == data) {

                $(this).remove();

            }

        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem with doing this ? Why doesn't it work ?

Comment: You should accept answers to your other questions, to motivate others to help you. This is how things are going on here

Comment: sorry man. I don't quite see the Accept button. I'll be happy to.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Yes, possible

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

```
$('div[comment_id="value"]').remove();
```

Comment: Vini: no, I don't have a clue what your code is doing and what should it be doing. I just gave you proper answer to your question.

Comment: My code is removing a div called comment with a custom attribute called comment_id based on this custom attribute comment_id.

Comment: I hardly recommend you to identify comments by `id` or `class` attributes, to be valid with (X)HTML DocType

Comment: What would be the best vanilla JavaScript alternative to this?