# How do you delete an item from a 'this' object in a jQuery function?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to delete an `<li>` item using the this.remove() function but I can't find the function in the DOM using Firebug:

jQuery

```
$( "#list_a, #list_b" ).sortable({
  connectWith: ".connected_sortable",
  receive: function(event, ui) {
    $("#list_b li").each(function() {
      if(ui.item.context.id == this.id)
        $(this).remove(); //<-----HOW DO I DELETE?  (also tried this.remove())
});}}}).disableSelection();
```

HTML

```
<ul id="list_a" class="connected_sortable">
  <li id="item_1">test text</li>
  <li id="item_3">test text</li>
  <li id="item_4">test text</li>
</ul>

<ul id="list_b" class="connected_sortable">
  <li id="item_3">test text</li>
</ul>
```

How would I go about deleting an `<li>` here? Please do not give me a direct reference solution - eg `$("#item_3").remove()` because I am trying to delete the other similiar id `<li>`.

Comment: Are you sure this statement: `ui.item.context.id == this.id` evaluates to true? `.remove(...)` *should* work, unless its never actually getting called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work.

```
$('#list_b li[id="'+ ui.item.context.id +'"]').remove();
```

this should replace the .each loop you have btw:

also, you should use `$(this).attr("id")` instead of `this.id` assuming you meant the jQuery element when y9ou said `this`, but try the above first me thinks.

also look at this question [JQuery. Remove element by attribute name. How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631594/jquery-remove-element-by-attribute-name-how)