# Remove element if it has a certain attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

So if I wanted to remove all `td` elements with an attribute of `style` for instance, how could I do that? Would I need to loop through all `td` elements or is there another method?

Thanks

Comment: Use an attribute selector: `$('td[style]').remove()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery. Remove element by attribute name. How?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631594/jquery-remove-element-by-attribute-name-how)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a selector to target them

```
$('td[style]').remove();
```

This selector is saying grab all `td` elements **with** attribute style